# Assistance wanted in removing the "No mail." notification in MOTD for Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, email

How do I remove the `No mail.` notification on Ubuntu 10.10 Server?
This occurs when I log in, and is located underneath the message of the day

I have a separate script which uses a different messaging system than the default one

Comment: Yes, send yourself a mail and you'll see 'You have new mail.' instead :D  Seriously though, why don't you want to be notified of the new mail upon logging in to a system?  It might be well important.

Answer (score 8):

That message is coming from the [`pam_mail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/pam_mail.8.html) module. Look in `/etc/pam.d/*` for calls to `pam_mail`. Replace `standard` or `empty` by `quiet` if you want to suppress `No mail` but keep the notification when there is mail. Replace by `nopen` to suppress the notification altogether.